Does the law restrict concert ticket re-sale in the UK?
EBay does not allow to sell concert, festival, sports, theatre and comedy tickets in the UK. (There is no such limitation in the US.)
Is there a law that makes concert etc. ticket re-sale in the UK problematic? Or is the UK eBay just establishing rules not warranted by law (which I would call capricious).

@Jen Establishing rules not warranted by law is what I call capricious, i.e. they just want it that way even though the law does not force them to do it.

Ticket master appears to allow you to resell them

@Greendrake why? It’s their businesss, they can do what they like with it.

@DaleM From legal standpoint, sure they can. From eBay sellers' standpoint, they behave odd (especially that their US branch does not).

Ticket resale, while regulated, is not prohibited or inherently problematic in the UK. See this March 2024 Parliamentary Report on Ticket Resales.
There are several established online ticket resellers that operate in the UK, including Viagogo and Seatwave. EBay UK operated StubHub UK in the UK market prior to StubHub UK's acquisition by Viagogo.

So, I reckon the current eBay policy is just part of their agreement to sell StubHub i.e. a non-compete clause?
